# How do I to grab the number of words in a post before it was updated, and store the number in a variable in the update method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When a post is updated I want to grab the number of words before it is saved and subtract that from the newly saved post word count. I want to do this in the post `update` controller.

Here is the `update` method

```
def update

  @guide                  = Guide.friendly.find(params[:guide_id])
  @post                   = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
  post_word_count_before  = #no idea how to get it
  post_word_count_after   = @post.post.scan(/\w+/).size
  change_in_words         = post_word_count_after - post_word_count_before

 if @post.update post_params
  PostContributer.create!(user_id: current_user.id, post_id: @post.id, no_of_contributions: 1, no_of_words_contributed: change_in_words)

  redirect_to guide_post_path(@guide, @post)
  flash[:success] = "Updated successfully"
 else
  render 'edit'
 end

end
```

I'm using `@post.post.scan(/\w+/).size` to get the word count after the post is updated. But I dont know how to get the word count before it is updated and store it in the variable `post_word_count_before`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@post` object is not changed until the `@post.update post_params` line, so the way you have it, the `post_word_count_after` variable contains the word count *before* the update.

I think this is what you are after:

```
def update

  @guide                  = Guide.friendly.find(params[:guide_id])
  @post                   = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
  post_word_count_before  = @post.post.scan(/\w+/).size

  if @post.update post_params
    post_word_count_after = @post.post.scan(/\w+/).size
    change_in_words       = post_word_count_after - post_word_count_before

    PostContributer.create!(user_id: current_user.id, post_id: @post.id, no_of_contributions: 1, no_of_words_contributed: change_in_words)

    redirect_to guide_post_path(@guide, @post)
    flash[:success] = "Updated successfully"
  else
    render 'edit'
  end

end
```

Comment: Could also probably just scan `params[:post][:post]`

Comment: Well that is handy. I just assumed it is updated when it hits the controller from the `POST` request the browser makes. I figured `if @post.update post_params` checks it has updated successfully, and diddnt also update at that point as well?

Comment: From the API docs for ActiveRecord.update: _Updates the attributes of the model from the passed-in hash and saves the record, all wrapped in a transaction. If the object is invalid, the saving will fail and false will be returned._

Answer (score 1):

`active_model` which is mixed into `active_record` provides API for record changes. You could use `record.changes` which provides `hash` of all the attributes that got changed with before and after values.

So instead of putting all that business logic in the `controller`, I would that rather move that into `model` where it belongs and with the use of `ActiveModel::Dirty` API and the `callbacks` you could achieve what you are after.

For example: Following could be your updated controller logic, clean and simple

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :load_guide, only [:update] # add other actions that require @guide
    before_action :load_post, only [:update] # add other actions that require @guide

    def update
        if @post.update(post_params)
            redirect_to(guide_post_path(@guide, @post), success: "Updated successfully") 
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    private
    def load_guide
        @guide = Guide.friendly.find(params[:guide_id])
    end

    def load_post   
        @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
        @post.contributer = current_user
    end 
end
```

And your updated model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attribute_accessor :contributer # to get the current_user info from controller

  before_update :create_post_contributer!

  def create_post_contributer!
    before = self.changes[:post][0].scan(/\w+/).size
    after = self.changes[:post][1].scan(/\w+/).size
    change_in_words = after - before

    PostContributer.create!(
      user_id: self.contributer.id, 
      post_id: self.id, 
      no_of_contributions: 1, 
      no_of_words_contributed: change_in_words
    )
  end 
end
```

Refer to [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changes) for more info.

Comment: If you go this route, I'd suggest moving the logic into the Post model itself and making it an attribute (e.g. in an `after_save` hook)

Answer (score 0):

**Try using it through session.**

**Store the previous updated value in session variable and delete the session variable once you do all the calculation from older post and newer post.**

Comment: I would strongly advise against putting random stuff in sessions, they are unpredictable. Remain as stateless as possible.